# How can I get this regex working the right way?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have 2 regex(es?).

Their job is to remove blank space from the source code. Let's call the first one Harrold and the second one John.

```
return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $buffer);
return preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $buffer);
```

Harrold plays it safe because it doesn't remove spaces () from the source code. He does remove whitespace, though.

John does the job right, and removes all spaces and whitespaces from the source code but leaves the necessary spaces, such as between text inside `<p>`. However, he doesn't minify the inside coding of a `<script>` tag.

How can I have Harrold and John to be working together? I want all the spaces and whitespaces removed (without removing necessary spaces inside any tags, such as `<p>`).

Is there any way to archieve this?

Comment: "He does remove whitespace, though". Spaces are included in whitespace.

Comment: Don't try to use regular expressions to parse HTML, use a DOM parser library. Then you can process the contents of different element types properly.

Comment: @Barmar What's it called? That mega long space you get when you press the tab button in notepad?

Comment: It's called a TAB character.

Comment: `\s` matches space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab, and some other Unicode whitespace characters.

Comment: There are many pre-written minifiers. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, especially so crudely. You need to parse all the element types properly.

Comment: @Barmar A tab character, because.. the tab button.. aha I get it. I'll just edit my question

Comment: If you just want to remove tab characters, use `\t`, not `\s`.

Comment: @Barmar Both really